# How were time dilation values predicted in the Hafele-Keating experiment?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

I am a high school student who is currently writing a report in which I need to give experimental evidence for time dilation. I have attempted to understand how the predicted values presented within the report were calculated, but I have failed to do so. I was wondering if someone would be willing to give me examples of how they would calculate the predicted time dilation of both the eastward and westward airplane, or rather, how Hafele or Keating would calculate the predicted time dilation of the eastward and westward plane.

Sorry if my question is not well put together, I'm new to this. For those who want to know what the predicted values are, I have attached the DOI of the original experiment below. If you want to view it for free, I'd recommend using Scihub.

DOI: 10.1126/science.177.4044.166

Comment: Doesn’t the paper you reference explain how it calculated the predicted values?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how they were calculated. They do explain how they were, but I'm still struggling to understand how the values were calculated as my level of ability within physics is rather low.

Comment: Kinematic time dilation is predicted by Special Relativity and depends on velocity. Gravitational time dilation is predicted by General Relativity and depends on gravitational potential. (Do you know what gravitational potential is?) It isn’t really clear from your question at what level you want to understand SR and GR. GR, in particular, is usually just explained very vaguely at the highschool level, if at all.

Comment: The planes’ paths were nontrivial so H&K had to integrate the time dilation over the path because it wasn’t constant. (Do you know what integration is?) They don’t even provide this path data as far as I can tell. They just give the integral to be done and the results of their integration.

Comment: I recommend that you ignore the nontrivial flight paths. Consider planes flying in equatorial orbits with constant speed at constant altitude. This should get you in the ballpark.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Ghost. I'll do something like that. Appreciate it.